# How to reuse the vuex module for other components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am working on **pagination** part in a project for a large **data**. I wanted to store my data inside **vuex**. But i did all my logic in  **vuex** store module. I wanted to reuse that particular module by creating an **instance** of it. Is it possible to create it ? or Creating an **service** would be better ? or a **mixins** can help by chance. But my main thing is that it should store that definitely in the **store** itself.

component1 -> new CommonStoreModule()
component2 -> new CommonStoreModule()

Help me to follow which approch and pattern would be most suitable.

Comment: It would probably help to show the code of your vuex module, and well as some code showing a component accessing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org) says: Vuex is a state management pattern + library for Vue.js applications. It serves as a **centralized store** for **all** the components in an application, with rules ensuring that the state can only be mutated in a predictable fashion.

If you want to share the logic in different components, then mixins is want you're looking for. [Mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) are a flexible way to distribute reusable functionalities for Vue components. A mixin object can contain any component options. When a component uses a mixin, all options in the mixin will be “mixed” into the component’s own options.

You can also mix both and access the centralized Vuex store from within the mixin.